# Console.WriteLine after async await call.

Tags: c#, http, asynchronous, httpclient

I'm completely new to using async calls and **await**. I have the below unit test function:

```
    public async static void POSTDataHttpContent(string jsonString, string webAddress)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(jsonString);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
            webAddress,
            stringContent);

        Console.WriteLine("response is: " + response);
    }
```

The test completes without error, but I never see the **Console.WriteLine** print statement show up in output - I'm not sure why. I've been looking around and it sounds like I may need to set this up as a task? Could someone point me in the proper direction?

Comment: Which test framework you are using? Micrsoft's own or NUnit? You might want to change the return type to `Task`

Comment: You probably want to change the return type to Task (not void - never use void as a return type if you can help it); you won't be able to await it otherwise. Also, put HttpClient in a using block.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft's.

Comment: Don't return `void` - you will lose all exception info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are already awaiting an `HttpResponseMessage`, a simple (and consistent) solution is to return `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`.

```
var x = await POSTDataHttpContent("test", "http://api/");

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> POSTDataHttpContent(
    string jsonString, string webAddress)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(jsonString);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
            webAddress,
            stringContent);

        Console.WriteLine("response is: " + response);

        return response;
    }
}
```

That said, you also need to ensure that your test setup is correct.  You cannot properly call an async method from a synchronous test.  Instead, mark your test `async` as well and await the method you are calling.  Furthermore, your test method must be marked as `async Task` as well since neither MS Test Runner nor other tools (NCrunch, NUnit) will properly deal with an async void test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestAsyncHttpCall()
{
    var x = await POSTDataHttpContent("test", "http://api/");
    Assert.IsTrue(x.IsSuccessStatusCode);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the best thing to do here for you would be to opt for a `Task` return type instead of a void.

```
public async Task POSTDataHttpContent(string jsonString, string webAddress)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(jsonString);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
            webAddress,
            stringContent);

        // Assert your response may be?
    }           
}
```

And if you are really adamant about not using Tasks (which is not a good idea):

```
public void POSTDataHttpContent(string jsonString, string webAddress)
{
    var Task = Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Run(async () => {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(jsonString);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
                webAddress,
                stringContent);


            return response;
        }
    });

    Task.Wait();
    Assert.IsNotNull(Task.Result);
}
```