# .NET async / await, was variable garbage collected?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, anglesharp

Playing around with [AngleSharp](https://anglesharp.github.io/), I'm facing a behaviour of **async/await** that I can ascribe only to garbage collector.

The following code don't print anything, but debugger states that `document.Title` has value `Google`.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
    var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
    var document = await context.OpenAsync("https://www.google.com/");
    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0} ", document.Title);
}
```

But if I save the property in a variable, it works as I expect printing `Title: Google`.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader();
    var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
    var document = await context.OpenAsync("https://www.google.com/");
    var title = document.Title;
    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0} ", title);
}
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Console.WriteLine after async await call.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520409/console-writeline-after-async-await-call)

Comment: Yep, @Jazb. Thank you! It perfectly explains what's happening.

Comment: good to hear :-)

Comment: Curious, how exactly did the link help?  Your `Main()` was *already* `async Task` as opposed to the dupe's `void` test method

Comment: I am more inclined to believe this is a bug in AngleSharp. the GC doesn't do stuff like that when it's working correctly, and it's **exceedingly** unlikely that you've stumbled into some bug in the GC. For this to be explained in any other way than that, you would need to produce a [mcve] that reproduces the same behavior _without_ AngleSharp.

Comment: @MickyD, it was helpful since using `using` solved the problem in an convenient way. What's the root cause is still not clear to me...

Comment: @PeterDuniho, interesting... In this way maybe some light maybe made.